How to double-slit experiment with an observer at home?
I decided to conduct Young's experiment, double-split experiment, observer effect. I bought a laser pointer, cut slits in the foil with the blade, as it should be. And this is what I got:


Light interference! That's the one. Who wants to repeat: Laser pointer -> 30 cm -> Slots -> 1 meter -> Screen (wall in my case).
It worked, great. But I would like to continue the experiment and connect the observer here. But nowhere on the Internet can I find information on how to do this? It is necessary some device capable to observe photons, but what is this device? Can anyone specifically name the device, model, how much it costs? From a minimal solution, to a professional one would be super as well. Thanks!

Your camera took the picture at the top. Just measure the distances between the brights and the darks.

@naturallyInconsistent didn't fully understand why need measure the distances between the brights and the darks? I want to get 2 lines instead interference picture, that's why I need connect device able observes for photos. I'm looking what the device I need?

You're not going to get 2 lines. What does your one-slit image look like?

@JEB Why not? If I will connect the observer device here I should see 2 lines, instead of interference

I think I know what you want to see now. The observer is not for photons, but rather for electron waves. If you want to reproduce it for photons, you should try using many polarisers

First of all, you will need to do the experiment with single photons! So your laser pointer is probably not gonna do the job. Then, if you want to detect the position of a photon (without absorbing it!) you have to resolve ultra-fine electromagnetic interactions. I am not an experimentalist, but I doubt that such a device exists on the free market, if at all, you can buy destructive single photon detectors on Thorlabs. In that case you do not see anything behind the detector.

It becomes a little easier, if you conduct the experiment with single electrons. If you can resolve their electromagnetic field you can detect through which slit they go and then eventually see two lines on the screen (which also has to be capable of detecting single electrons).

Maybe measure the one slit image, and post it? In theory, blocking one slit is an observation device.

the observer expt was done with electrons not photons
